# Knockout js displaying a filtered list in a child object. Accessing the parent object list to filter

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I currently have a list of students and a list of classes in a school object. I would like each class object to be able to display a filtered list of students based on the class id property.

I have tried to access the parent object via custom binding but have not had any success.

Perhaps I am looking at the problem the wrong way? I have spent a couple days on this and whichever way I tackle it I always need to access a value on a parent object.

Are there any methods of accessing what I need? I am beginning to think that it is not possible to access a global style variable.

```
function School()
{
  var self = this;
  self.ClassVMs = ko.observableArray([]).indexed('Number');
  self.ChildVMs = ko.observableArray([]).indexed('Number');
}

function ClassVM(classId, text)
{
  var self = this;
  self.Number = ko.observable();
  self.Text =  ko.observable(text);
  self.ClassId = ko.observable(classId);
}

function ChildVM(classId, text)
{
  var self = this;
  self.Number = ko.observable();
  self.ClassId = ko.observable(classId);
  self.Text = ko.observable(text);
}
```

I have a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrSmith_/rtvsxomp/) with my setup. Any and all guidance is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: i'm not sure what you are looking at . can you elaborate on your final output you looking at . In mean time you seem to use `fn` tough $index() prop available in view .

Comment: Sure. I am looking to make my ClassVM objects contain a filtered list from the school.ChildVMs() collection.

Comment: i see name & id collection in childVMs object after push. `filtered list` ? i'm not sure what does it mean ? what need to be filtered or are you looking to make `1 english jhony` kindoff output ? sample output here http://jsfiddle.net/rtvsxomp/93/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes I can see how it could be considered a bit of an XY problem. You both made look at it differently which was a great help.

The way I originally would have liked wasn't looking feasible. My compromise was to add a computed to the root view model and display the list this way.

```
function School()
{
    var self = this;
    self.ClassVMs = ko.observableArray([]).indexed('Number');
    self.ChildVMs = ko.observableArray([]).indexed('Number');

    self.DisplayClassId = ko.observable(1);
    self.Display = function(x)
    {
        console.log(x);
        self.DisplayClassId(x);
    }
 }

    var viewModel = new School();
    viewModel.filteredItems = ko.computed(function () {
    var filter = viewModel.DisplayClassId();
    if (!filter) { 
        return viewModel.ChildVMs();
    } else {
        var filtered = ko.utils.arrayFilter(viewModel.ChildVMs(), function (item) {
            return (item.ClassId() === filter);
        });
        return filtered;
    }
  })
```

[Fiddle for reference](http://jsfiddle.net/MrSmith_/7xn7ercv/)

Comment: Feel free to mark your own answer as accepted if this was the way you ended up solving the problem. Glad you found a solution that works for you, thx for sharing.

Answer (score 2):

You do *not* need global variables to solve this. Knockout has `$root` and `$parent` to step slightly outside of the scope you're in inside a `foreach`. In addition, if really needed, you can always make sure the view models get another type of view model as its dependency. In fact, if one view model has a list of sub view models it already has such a dependency.

What you need to think about is what your UI/UX is going to be like. Are you designing your view models to support a view where the user is "viewing" a student and enrolls him/her in classes? Or is the app user viewing a class and adding students one by one?

Here's a variant that shows a little bit of both:

```js
function School(classes) {
  var self = this;
  self.classes = ko.observableArray(classes);
  self.students = ko.observableArray([]);
  self.enroll = function(child, someClass) {
    if (self.students().indexOf(child) < 0) {
      self.students.push(child);
    }
    if (someClass.students().indexOf(child) < 0) {
      someClass.students.push(child);
    }
  };
  self.enrollNewChild = function(someClass) {
    if (!!someClass.childToBeEnrolled()) {
      self.enroll(someClass.childToBeEnrolled(), someClass);
      someClass.childToBeEnrolled(null);
    }
  };
  self.enrollInClass = function(child) {
    if (!!child.classToBeEnrolledIn()) {
      self.enroll(child, child.classToBeEnrolledIn());
      child.classToBeEnrolledIn(null);
    }
  };
}

function Class(id, txt) {
  var self = this;
  self.id = ko.observable(id);
  self.txt = ko.observable(txt);
  self.students = ko.observableArray([]);
  self.studentsCsv = ko.computed(function() {
    return self.students().map(function(s) { return s.txt(); }).join(", ");
  });
  self.childToBeEnrolled = ko.observable(null);
}

function Child(id, txt) {
  var self = this;
  self.id = ko.observable(id);
  self.txt = ko.observable(txt);
  self.classToBeEnrolledIn = ko.observable(null);
}

var english = new Class(1, "English 1");
var math1 = new Class(2, "Mathematics 1");
var math2 = new Class(2, "Mathematics 2");

var john = new Child(1, "John Doe");
var mary = new Child(1, "Mary Roe");
var rick = new Child(1, "Rick Roll");
var marc = new Child(1, "Marcus Aurelius");

var school = new School([english, math1, math2]);

ko.applyBindings(school);

// Method 1:
school.enroll(john, english);
school.enroll(john, math2);
school.enroll(marc, english);
school.enroll(mary, math2);
school.enroll(mary, english);
school.enroll(rick, english);
school.enroll(rick, math1);
```

```css
td { background-color: #eee; padding: 2px 10px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<h3>Classes:</h3>
<table>
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: classes">
    <tr>
      <td><span data-bind="text: txt"></span></td>
      <td><span data-bind="text: studentsCsv"></span></td>      
      <td>
        Add student
        <select data-bind="options: $root.students, value: childToBeEnrolled, optionsText: 'txt', optionsCaption: 'Choose...'"></select>
        <button data-bind="click: $root.enrollNewChild">enroll now</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<h3>School Students</h3>
<table>
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: students">
    <tr>
      <td><span data-bind="text: txt"></span></td>
      <td>
        Enroll in:
        <select data-bind="options: $root.classes, optionsText: 'txt', value: classToBeEnrolledIn, optionsCaption: 'Choose...'"></select>
        <button data-bind="click: $root.enrollInClass">enroll now</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

It does *not* answer your question directly ("*display a filtered list of students based on the class id property*") because I think that's an XY-problem, and you're better off trying to find a solution like the above where you have proper references instead of having to use `id` and some kind of lookup mechanism.